# Popup Form cannot be submitted for k=1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

If i click this button ,

```
<input href="#medicine-patient1<?php echo $k; ?>" type='submit' name='form_edit<?php echo $k; ?>' class='medicine medicine-btn someClass'  value='' title="Medicine"  />
```

a popup form is displayed,`

```
 <div style="display:none;">
      <div id="medicine-patient1<?php echo $k; ?>" class="medicine-patient-pop">
      <form name="medicine1<?php echo $k; ?>" id="medicine1<?php echo $k; ?>" method="post" action="edit_medicine_dosage.php">
        <div class="patient-form">
          <h1>Change medicine dosage</h1>
          <?php
 $group1 = getgroupdataId($db);
$group_id = getgroupId($db,$group);
$patgrp_id = $group_id['groupid'];
//echo $group;
//echo $k;
 ?>



           <input type="hidden" name="patient_username" value="<?=$usernam?>">
               <label>Group:</label>
              <select  name="group" id="group"  onchange="list_group1(this.value,<?php echo $k; ?>)" class="group-select">
                <option value="<?php echo $group ; ?>" > <?php echo $group ; ?></option>
                <?php
                                        for($i = 0; $i < count($group1); $i++) {
                                            $grp = $group1[$i];
                                            $grp_name = $grp['groupname'];
                                            $grp_id = $grp['groupid'];
                                        echo '<option value="'.$grp_id.'">'.$grp_name.'</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
              </select>
              <br clear="all" />

            <div id="hidden<?php echo $k; ?>">
                <?php 

   $getpatdetails = getUserdataId($db, $pid);

    $insulin_name = $getpatdetails["insulin_name"];
    $tablet_name = $getpatdetails["tablet_name"];
    $current_dosins_values = $getpatdetails["current_dosins_values"];
    $current_dostab_values = $getpatdetails["current_dostab_values"];

    $insln=explode('#', $insulin_name);

    $current_dosins = explode("_",$current_dosins_values);
    $current_dostab = explode("_",$current_dostab_values);
    //echo $insln[0];

    $ins_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM insulin WHERE groupid='$patgrp_id'") or die(mysql_error());
     $tab_name= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablet WHERE groupid='$patgrp_id'") or die(mysql_error());
     $l=1; 
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($ins_name))
    {
     $cur_ins1 = explode(",",$current_dosins[$l-1]);
     ?>
     <label>Name of Insulin <?=$l?>:</label>
                                <select  name="ins_name[<?=$l?>]" id="dropdown<?=$l?>" class="group-select"  onChange="return getSelectedField2()" >
                                <option value="<?php echo $insln[$l-1]; ?>"><?php echo $insln[$l-1]; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                if($admin_type=='phar')
                                {
                                    $pins=mysql_query("SELECT insulinname FROM pharinsulin WHERE adm_id='$admin_id'");
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pins))
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row['insulinname'].'">'.$row['insulinname'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $insulin=$row2['insulin'];
                                    $ins_data = explode("#",$insulin);
                                    foreach($ins_data as $key1=>$ins)
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$ins.'">'.$ins.'</option>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>

                            <br clear="all" />

                            <label>
                                <input type="text" id="insulin<?=$l?>" name="insulin[<?=$l?>]" value="Change Dosage" disabled style="width:200px; height: 35px; color:#5e5e5e; background: none; border:0px; margin: -5px 0px 0px -5px;" />
                            </label>
                            <select  name="ins_morn_dos[insulin<?=$l?>]" class="dosage-select" >
                              <option value="<?=$cur_ins1['0']?>"><?=$cur_ins1['0']?></option>
                              <?php
                                                        for ($i = 0; $i < 37; $i++) {
                                                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                            </select>
                            <select  name="ins_noon_dos[insulin<?=$l?>]" class="dosage-select">
                              <option value="<?=$cur_ins1['1']?>"><?=$cur_ins1['1']?></option>
                              <?php
                                                    for ($i = 0; $i < 37; $i++) {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                            </select>
                            <select  name="ins_even_dos[insulin<?=$l?>]" class="dosage-select">
                              <option value="<?=$cur_ins1['2']?>"><?=$cur_ins1['2']?></option>
                              <?php
                                                    for ($i = 0; $i < 37; $i++) {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                            </select>
                            <br clear="all" />
```

please don't get irritated with the queries and all.The problem is that I'm not able to submit the form if the value of k=1.Everything works except for k=1.Queries are working properly.Please don't get confused by the php codes.

Comment: have you tried displaying simple popup ?

Comment: Are you seeing any error on console of your browser?

Comment: can you provide us a JSFiddle please

Comment: `<input href="#medicine-patient1<?php echo $k; ?>" type='submit'..`?????

Comment: @voodoo417 its the button to be clicked so as to get the popup form.

Comment: @Aditya:No...error....but the form is invisible if I inspect the element(inspect code) although it is displayed on the page.